# remove " \r\n " from authorization headers

Tags: javascript, axios, request

I'm facing an issue when making a post request,

I'm passing the **jwt in the headers** but somehow when passing the token it adds an \r\n at the end so I get an unauthorized 401. If I try the same request in Postman it works.

My headers look like

```
_header: 'POST /my/post/url\r\n' +
        'Accept: accept\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: content\r\n' +
        'Authorization: jsonWebToken\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
```

Comment: `My headers look like` - thats exactly what raw headers look like - `\r\n` delimit each header so one knows where one header ends and the next begins

Comment: the first word in an Authoirization header should be `Basic` or `Digest` ... yours is `jsonWebToken`

Comment: It actually was Bearer (mytoken) but didn't want to put the entire token, I was logging it in the console, so that's why it was different with all of those end of lines

Comment: anyway, if what you're showing are **raw** headers, then that's fine ... but what is `_header`? something you created, you tagged `axios`, but that's not how you add headers to axios